# matlab: regexp and split, and picking some cells

Tags: regex, string, matlab, split, format

I have the following input:

```
>> data(1).Header
ans =
  AF051909 |392-397:CAGCTG| |413-418:CAGGTG|
```

I needed to save them to cells as `{'392-397', 'CAGCTG'; '413-418', 'CAGGTG';}`

I so I used regexp to do so with the following code:

```
struKm(1).trueBinding = regexp(data(1).Header,'\s\||\:|\|','split');
```

this returns:

```
>> struKm(1).trueBinding
ans = 
  'AF051909'    '392-397'    'CAGCTG'    ''    '413-418'    'CAGGTG'    ''
```

as you can see there are to empty cells and I tried two find out why they are there but failed.

I also tried to ignore that and continue to picking up the cell that I need for the rest of my code which is `'CAGCTG'` and `'CAGGTG'`. I have this code to pick them up:

```
[r1,r2] = ismember(struKm(1).trueBinding,set)
```

it return zeros.

Can someone help with two issues please?

Regards, A.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you just want to extract the only two nucleotide sequences from that cell array. If that's the case this seems to work:

```
atgc = @(str) (sum(lower(str)==97 | lower(str)==116 | lower(str) == 103 ...
    | lower(str) == 99)==numel(str)) && numel(str)~=0;
data(1).Header = 'AF051909 |392-397:CAGCTG| |413-418:CAGGTG|';
result1 = regexp(data(1).Header,'\s\||\:|\|','split');
results = result(cellfun(atgc,result1))
```

This gives

```
results = 

    'CAGCTG'    'CAGGTG'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to match instead of splitting:

```
match = regexp(data(1).Header,'\|(.*?):(.*?)\|','tokens');
```

Now match will contain two cell arrays:

```
>> match
match = 
    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}
```

Which you can access like this:

```
>> match{1}
ans = 
    '392-397'    'CAGCTG'
>> match{2}
ans = 
    '413-418'    'CAGGTG'
```

To get this cell array of cell arrays into the form you originally requested, you can do this:

```
>> struKm(1).trueBinding = cat(1,match{:})
struKm(1).trueBinding = 
    '392-397'    'CAGCTG'
    '413-418'    'CAGGTG'
```